# How to get a part of path

Tags: java, file, java-8, java-stream

Hi I have a question I have function that returns me all files in `List<String>` there are few lines of files that ends with `.pom` i.e. the path is `C://poms/xx/interested-2.0.pom` how could I get just the `interested` because i.e. this is name of the `pom` should I use `split` or is there a better way to do that in `Java 8`any suggestions?

```
public List<String> listFiles(String path, List<File> files) {

    File directory = new File(path);

    File[] fList = directory.listFiles();
    if (fList != null) {
        for (File f : fList) {
            if (f != null && f.isFile()) {
                files.add(f);
            } else if (f.isDirectory()) {
                listFiles(f.getAbsolutePath(), files);
            }
        }
    }

    return files.stream()
            .filter(file -> file.toString().endsWith(".xml"))
            .map(File::toString)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without making too many changes to your original code you could just do :

```
return files.stream().filter(file -> file.toString().endsWith(".xml"))
                     .map(File::getName)
                     .map(s -> s.split("-")[0])
                     .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Rather than fetching the entire path of the file, just get the *name* of the file.

Answer (score 0):

To get file name only you can use [`Path.getFileName`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html#getFileName--) :

```
String fileName = Paths.get(path).getFileName(); // interested-2.0.pom
String result = fileName.split("-")[0];
```

**Edit**: You can also use [`listFiles(FileFilter filter)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/?java/io/File.html) :

```
public List<String> listFiles(String path) {

    File directory = new File(path);
    File[] fList = directory.listFiles(p -> p.getName().endsWith(".xml"));
    if (fList != null) {
        return Arrays.stream(files)
                .map(file -> file.getName().split("-")[0])
                .collect(toList());
    }
    throw new RuntimeException("No files");
}
```